# Is it true that Arizal said even Jesus’s neshama will receive a tikkun but that it will take 50,000 yovels for that to happen?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, christianity, arizal, gehinnom

I’ve heard this claim from Rav Moshe Weinberger but I wonder whether or not it’s true (that the Arizal said this). Please provide sources.

Comment: That seems to contradict the Gemara Rosh Hashana 17a (iirc) that those who lead the public astray go to Gehinnom and don't leave.

Comment: That sounds more like the Ramchal who says that ultimately every *neshama* has a *tikkun*.